# SQL Server XQuery always returning null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, xquery

I'm learning how to read XML using SQL and currently struggling to return the desired data that I was expecting.

For the given example, I'm expecting to return "tagFourData" with the value of "Data". Instead I always seem to get NULL

```
declare @data xml = '<object>
    <Overview Requester="Me">
        <Request GetData="Y" Title="Get First SQL DataSet in XML" Id="1">
            <Detailed tagOne="yap" tagTwo="Yap">
                <!--Further elements/attributes if needed -->
            </Detailed>
        </Request>
        <Request GetData="N" Title="Get Second SQL DataSet in XML" Id="2">
            <Detailed tagThree="yap" tagFour="Yap">
                <!--Further elements/attributes if needed -->
            </Detailed>
        </Request>
        <Request GetData="Y" Title="Get Third SQL DataSet in XML" Id="3">
            <Detailed tagFour="Data" tagFive="data2" />
        </Request>
    </Overview>
</object>'

select @data.value('(object/Overview/Request/Detailed/tagFour/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as tagFourData
```

Is there something wrong with how I've written my Select statement?

Preferable also looking at a solution which can be dynamic. That is to say tagFour could be under a completely different Id but the structure Object/Overview/Request/Detailed would always be the same
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
select @data.value('(object/Overview/Request/Detailed/@tagFour)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as tagFourData
```

Need an extra `@` to indicate attribute instead of child element.

But I'm not sure how you would generalize this further, as additional items inside the `Detailed` element are **not** children of the `@tagFour` attribute for purposes of an XPath query. Once you select into an attribute, *you have selected into the attribute*, and children of that attribute's element are no longer part of the same path.

Comment: Thank you for this. I can see the @ used for attribute on the documentation after rereading reading over. Can I ask why we didn't need to use the node() field?